# How do I pass my access token via javascript with IdentityServer3?

Tags: identityserver3

I have an Asp.Net MVC app with a lot of javascript calls. I've protected an MVC action, get redirected to the identity server, login, and then get redirected back to the client. I can make subsequent calls through MVC, but how do I get that access token and use it in ajax calls?

Here's my Startup.cs file:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Tell Microsoft to not try to map to .Net's ClaimsTypes
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
    });

    const string svcUrl = "https://localhost/svc.security";

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = svcUrl,
        ClientId = "nedd_client",
        RedirectUri = "http://localhost:61207/",
        ResponseType = "code id_token token",

        // Ask for 'roles' claims & for access to web services
        Scope = "openid profile",

        SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",

        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
            {
                // filter "protocol" claims
                var claims = new List<Claim>(from c in n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims
                                             where c.Type != "iss" &&
                                                   c.Type != "aud" &&
                                                   c.Type != "nbf" &&
                                                   c.Type != "exp" &&
                                                   c.Type != "iat" &&
                                                   c.Type != "nonce" &&
                                                   c.Type != "c_hash" &&
                                                   c.Type != "at_hash"
                                             select c);

                // Get userinfo data
                var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(new Uri(svcUrl + "/connect/userinfo"), n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken);

                var userInfo = await userInfoClient.GetAsync();
                userInfo.Claims.ToList().ForEach(ui => claims.Add(new Claim(ui.Item1, ui.Item2)));

                // Get access token
                var tokenClient = new OAuth2Client(new Uri(svcUrl + "/connect/token"), "nedd_client", "secret");

                var response = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(n.Code, n.RedirectUri);

                claims.Add(new Claim("access_token", response.AccessToken));
                claims.Add(new Claim("expires_at", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(response.ExpiresIn).ToLocalTime().ToString()));
                claims.Add(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

                n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsIdentity(claims.Distinct(new ClaimComparer()), n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType), n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
            },
        }

    });

}
```

And here's a sample ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "https://localhost/svc.security/connect/userinfo",
    //headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + my.getAccessToken() },   // get access token from cookie?

}).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    show(JSON.parse(jqXHR.response));
```

Comment: Can't you just store the Access Token in local storage on the web browser? The Access Token does not need to be kept secret. If it is tampered with the fact that it is signed would prevent it from being accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I realized that my real problem was the fact that, after logging in, the cookie was an ASP.Net server cookie and not accessible to the client.

I added a method to my MVC controller for javascript to retrieve the token that the server already had.

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult GetAccessToken()
    {
        var token = (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).FindFirst("access_token");
        if (token != null)
        {
            return Content(token.Value);
        }

        return Content("");
    }
```

Then my javascript would look something like this, calling it to get the token before making the ajax call to the web service.

```
function getAccessToken() {
    var returnVal = "";

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:61207/Home/GetAccessToken", false);
    xhr.send();
    returnVal = xhr.responseText;

    return returnVal;
}
```

There may be a different solution that is more elegant, but once I had clear in mind what was available at the client and server, this seemed the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think after login successfully, you should keep the token some where (in cookie for example), then your "my.getAccessToken()" should read from there.

This example does similar https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/Clients/JavaScriptImplicitClient/index.html

```
 if (window.location.hash) {
        handleCallback();
    }
```

Comment: Haz, that works fine for a pure javascript app, but doesn't work with a mix of MVC and ajax. I figured it out and posted my own answer below.

Comment: Understand your fix. It works but should be improved for efficiency as an additional request is needed before each main request. Sorry I cannot comment on your answer due to my "points" ;)